# Get data from HttpContext Angular and Web API

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

In the angular controller I have this code to transfer $scope.myModel to a Web API controller:

```
$scope.upload[index] = $upload.upload({
  url: settings.constants.uploadURL,
  headers: { 'myHeaderKey': 'myHeaderVal' },
  data: { model: $scope.myModel },
  file: $file,
  fileFormDataName: 'myFile'
}).then(function (response) { ...
```

The Web API controller post method looks like this

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post()
{
  return UploadFile(HttpContext.Current);
}
```

How do I get the data: model from out from the HttpContext??

Comment: They are in the not existing parameter of your Post method

Answer (score 0):

WebAPI is not designed to be used in that fashion. Specifically, it is usually bad practice to refer to `HttpContext.Current` from within a WebAPI controller method. If you did want to check the request or response, you should refer to them by the properties of the `ApiController` base class, see the [msdn docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller(v=vs.118).aspx).

Usually, people prefer model binding for situations like this. Suppose you had in js:

```
{
   foo: "bar"
}
```

You should declare a class in C# that maps to it:

```
public class MyRequestModel
{
   public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

And by declaring your API method:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(MyRequestModel mdl)
{
// do stuff, mdl.Foo will have "bar" in it magically
}
```

This results in more object-oriented ways of transferring data from javascript to C#. It's more typesafe because you can be guaranteed that the `Foo` property in C# will have a `string`, or an `int`, or whatever you declare it to be as opposed to parsing the request yourself.

Comment: Thanks. It is used to upload files to the server and blobstorage, but I need to send a model with data along. I try the solution you described :)

Comment: If you plan on sending binary data along with a serialized model, then you will need to do more than I described. It's actually fairly complicated to read the underlying request stream in WebAPI, but here's a good link: http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Dec/13/Accepting-Raw-Request-Body-Content-with-ASPNET-Web-API